# PHP count from database WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am trying to show a count of all applications stored in a database with the status of `1`.

Here is my **UPDATED** code:

```
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member ")or die('You need to add an administrator ' );

$counter = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as personID FROM member where state='1' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $personID = $row['personID'];

$num = mysql_fetch_array($counter);
$countadmin = $num["personID"];
```

However this isn't showing anything when I echo `$countadmin'

Can anyone help

Comment: I can see by the code you posted that you just started with php + mysql programming. Well, get rid of the mysql functions and give a look at the PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Try to run the query in phpmyadmin and see if it returns anything.

Comment: See updated code above

Comment: The variable you assign is `$countadmin`, not `$countpending`.

Comment: @Barmar... i have changed this... still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
$query = mysql_query("select count(*) from member where state='1'");
if ($query) {
    $count = mysql_result($query, 0, 0);
    echo $count;
}
```

Check [mysql_result](https://www.php.net/mysql_result) and also notice the `Warning` at top. Also make sure that, the field is `state` not `status`, it's confusing, you mentioned `status` in your question but used `state` in the query.

Also, following line is not required to get the `count` of your second `query`

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member ")or die('You need to add an administrator ' );
```

Also, make sure that, you have [connected](https://www.php.net/mysql_connect) to a database and [selected](https://www.php.net/mysql_select_db) it.

Answer (score 0):

You try to readout "ID", but you select COUNT as "personID"

Comment: This still isn't working, please see updated question

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here;

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `Status`='1'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`Status`) FROM `member` WHERE `Status`='1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $Count = $row['count(Status)'];
}
```

Comment: I guess ID was one of your columns. Replace it with an actual column header. Also, just to clarify, in option one the variable $num_rows holds the value and in option two $Count holds the value.